# python setuptools arguments to develop

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a custom command called `CustomCSS` defined in my setup.py file. The command takes two arguments, and does some processing on it. The arguments are defined like:

```
class CustomCSS(BaseCommand):
    description = "Site level customizations"
    user_options = [
        ('css=', None, 'Specify the path to the custom css file'),
        ('logo=', None, 'Specify the logo to use'),
    ]
```

In my `run` method, I can use these arguments like:

```
def run(self):
    if not self.should_run():
        print('No Custom CSS or logo')
        return
```

My command mapping is:

```
setup_args['cmdclass'] = {
    'custom': CustomCSS,
    'js': Bower,
    'css': CSS,
    'build_py': js_css_first(build_py, strict=is_repo),
    'sdist': js_css_first(sdist, strict=True),
    'bdist_egg': bdist_egg if 'bdist_egg' in sys.argv else bdist_egg_disabled,
}
```

This command works on it's own independently, and accepts the arguments. However, I also need to run this command with `python setup.py develop`. I managed to add the command to run with `python setup.py develop` using the following code:

```
from setuptools.command.develop import develop
class develop_js_css(develop):
    def run(self):
        if not self.uninstall:
            self.distribution.run_command('custom')
            self.distribution.run_command('js')
            self.distribution.run_command('css')
```

However, the develop command does not accept arguments. I tried adding arguments using the same syntax as the `CustomCSS` command, but the command refuses the arguments.

Is there a way I can pass the arguments to the develop command?